# WHMCS Wrong admin URL

Tags: url, whmcs

By mistake, while configuravo WHMCS I entered the wrong URL in the admin URL, so right now if I try to go in the customer area, use the leads me wrong. How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

The admin URL is set by adding the following code `$customadminpath = "mycustomfoldername";` in configuration.php file , you can read more about that in the WHMCS [documentation](http://docs.whmcs.com/Customising_the_Admin_Directory)

Comment: a quick solution indeed